# Xcode 6.3: Swift String 'characters' property not found

Tags: string, swift

When I copy the example from Apple Swift manual to my code

```
 for character in "Dog!".characters {
        print(character)
    }
```

I get error message

> Could not find member characters

What has happened to 'characters' property in Xcode 6.3 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String property characters is only available in Xcode 7 (Swift 2.0). Just delete `.characters` and it will work with Xcode 6.3 (Swift 1.2).

```
for character in "Dog!" {
    println(character)
}
```

Comment: What is only available in Xcode 7?  Your version or the asker's version?

Comment: @nhgrif  String property .characters. I have both versions here

Comment: Thank you, Leo, it really works without 'characters'.. Let's hope that the app will be compatible with ios 9 :)